# How to create a rootless Docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to avoid having a ton of permission errors with my docker container when it creates new files. As such, I followed this article: https://vsupalov.com/docker-shared-permissions/

It just simply suggests passing the current user and group IDs to the docker build process. I'm trying to do that with `docker -compose`, but having a ton of issues because it doesn't like the dollar signs.

Here's what my `docker-compose.yml` file looks like on the top:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
        - USER_ID=${id -u}
        - GROUP_ID=${id -g}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-20-38-52:~/goku$ docker-compose build app
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "build" option in service "app": "USER_ID=${id -u}"
```

I have tried various things, including `$$(id -u)`, `$(id -u)`, and the same thing for `id -g`. Same error for both.

I have even tried using `environment` as opposed to args, such as:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
      - USER_ID=$$(id -u)
      - GROUP_ID=$$(id -g)
```

I have also tried the following:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      args:
        - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379/0
        - USER_ID=$${id -u}
        - GROUP_ID=$${id -g}
```

This just turns into this error:

```
Step 1/16 : FROM ruby:2.5.8-buster
 ---> fc5e02c64ca4
Step 2/16 : ARG USER_ID
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6dcd7b5124a2
Step 3/16 : ARG GROUP_ID
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cf8d3e88a3a2
Step 4/16 : RUN groupadd --gid $GROUP_ID ubuntu
 ---> Running in ab3496006746
groupadd: invalid group ID '${id'
The command '/bin/sh -c groupadd --gid $GROUP_ID ubuntu' returned a non-zero code: 3
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build
```

Still no luck.

Comment: Just a quick aside, LewlSauce: in general, the community prefers contributions that are free of chatty or conversational material. Stack Overflow is closer to Wikipedia in its editing model that, say, a social media website or a chatroom. Question and answer artifacts are intended to be preserved for years, decades even - and thus there is no need to record thanks, greetings, etc.

Comment: I sometimes post this advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use speech marks, because of the spaces, when your variables are expanded, the `REDIS_URL` variable does not have a space and does not break your script also.